# I've got a problem with a probability exercise about a nonsymmetric coin and I don't know from where some certain equations are coming from

Tags: probability

Let there be a coin where the probability for obverse is not 1/2 but instead is equal to p, if $A_{n}$ is equal to the probability when the number of obverse = number of reverse after n tests, then why is

$P\left(A_{2k}\right)=p^k\cdot \left(1-p\right)^k\cdot \binom{2k}{k}$

And $P\left(A_{2k-1}\right)= 0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean "obverse" instead of "observe"—that is, the front side?  (Likewise for "reverse" in place of "reserve"—the back side.)

Comment: Yes sorry for the typo

Comment: Assuming that's the case, the first expression is the probability (from the formula for the  [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)) that out of $2k$ flips, $k$ come up heads ("obverse") and two come up tails ("reverse").  The second expression is just a representation of the fact that when you flip a coin an odd number of times, there's no way for heads and tails to come up an equal number of times.

Comment: Ok, but from where does $p^k\cdot \left(1-p\right)^k$ come from?

Comment: It's explained in the Wikipedia page I linked to, but essentially, $p^k$ provides the probability of the first $k$ flips coming up heads, and $(1-p)^k$ provides the probability of the last $k$ flips coming up tails.  But of course, the flips don't have to come with all of the heads first, and all of the tails after.  There are lots of different ways the heads and tails could have been scattered in the $2k$ flips.  The binomial coefficient $\binom{2k}{k}$ counts those ways; that's why we multiply by that.

Comment: There's an edit link under the question, you can correct the typos.